# fazer um button para encerrar sessão de usuário (asp)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Gente estou desenvolvendo um site que possibilita que o usuário logue em sua conta e tal, porém preciso q depois q ele logue esse botão de login suma e apareça um pra encerrar a sessão (um botão sair).

```
<nav class="acceder">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <asp:Label id="login" runat="server" Text="Entrar">

            </asp:Label>
            <div id="login-content">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" placeholder="Usuário" runat="server" CssClass="user"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" placeholder="Senha" runat="server" CssClass="pass" TextMode="Password"> </asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEntrar" runat="server" Text="Entrar" CssClass="submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não invente a roda! Regra número 1 do desenvolvimento de sistemas :-)

Use o controle `LoginView` que já implementa essa lógica e facilita muito. Abaixo uma ideia, baseada na parte de código que você forneceu, de como vai se **parecer** o seu código final. Você precisa apenas adaptá-lo ao seu código real:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEntrar" runat="server" Text="Entrar" CssClass="submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" OnLoggingOut="HeadLoginStatus_LoggingOut"
                LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" LogoutText="Sair" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Esse controle automaticamente exibe um template para usuários anônimos (não logados) e para usuários autenticados (logados). Isso é exatamente o que você pretende realizar manualmente (*O* `OnLogginOut` *talvez não precise ser tratado no seu código*).

Leia mais sobre o controle aqui: [Classe LoginView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Para saber mais sobre os controles de login do ASP.NET que automatizam essas tarefas que você parece estar fazendo à mão dê uma lida em: [Visão Geral sobre Controles de Login ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178329(v=vs.110).aspx)